# How to register a container in systemd-machined?

Tags: systemd, container

I have a few docker containers on Fedora 34, but they are not listed with `machinectl list -a`. Only the "physical" machine is listed.

I have running the service **systemd-machined** but is as if containers where not registered.

How can I register a container in `systemd-machined`?

Answer (score 0):

I found your question searching for the same answer you're looking for.

Here's what I found [HERE](https://www.admin-magazine.com/Archive/2016/32/networkd-and-nspawn-in-systemd):

"*The systemd-machined.service container registration manager manages containers and other virtual systems and uses the machinectl tool for easy access. To create a new container, you can download suitable images of the desired distribution in RAW, TAR, or Docker format and then launch a container based on your choice of image.*"

If you raised your containers up using with Docker directly instead of using the `machinectl start`, you won't see them in the output of `machinectl list -a`

In ubuntu, you don't get it unless you expressly install it. Try to run the `machinectl` command in Ubuntu and you get the error:

"*Command 'machinectl' not found, but can be installed with:
sudo apt install systemd-container*"

Hope this helps you out-